# Get fulldate in fullcalendar eventDrop

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How can I get fulldate of the specific position from eventDrop?

**Fulldate Example:**

**Current Position:** 2013-12-20

**Dragged Position:** 2013-12-11

I want Dragged Position in '2013-12-11' form. Is it possible ?

**Here is my code:**

```
// ----- This Paramenter is Used for Draging Events ------ //   

eventDrop   : function(event, delta) {

       alert(delta);

// -- Right now its just providing days in '+' or '-'
// -- I want fulldate where it was dragged to: e.g 2013-12-11
}
```

Right now its just providing days in '+' or '-' .

I want fulldate where it was dragged to: e.g 2013-12-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer** (to get the modified date of the event)

The modified date of the event is stored in the `event.start` property of the event object that is passed into the `eventDrop` callback.  Basically, fullcalendar modifies the event object before invoking the callback.

**Previous Answer** (to get the original date of the event)

I haven't been able to find a way to directly access the original date from the eventDrop callback, since fullcalendar has already modified the event date.

I use the following workaround:

```
(function() {    
   var originalDate;

   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      // Always called before eventDrop
      eventDragStart: function(event) {
         originalDate = new Date(event.start);  // Make a copy of the event date
      },

      eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta) {
         alert( 'Event dropped!  Original date = ' + originalDate );
      }
   }
})();
```

As shown in the code, the idea is just to tuck away the original date in the eventDragStart callback that is guaranteed to be called before the event drop callback.

Comment: Basically I need the date where It is dragged to, not the date from where it was dragged

Comment: Sorry, I missed what you were asking.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @CodeHunter I've updated my answer to better address your question.  Could you please accept my updated answer if it's helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

eventDrop: function(event,revertFunc) {

var CurrentPositionDate= $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy/MM/dd');

}
});

Here **currentPositionDate** contain the date of current position date after drop event.

**Just put this code in your script Its work for me....Thanks**